# React view only gets fresh data on page reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a simple campgrounds CRUD app to get some practice with the MERN stack and Redux.

Adding a campground is working fine. I'm routing to the campgrounds list page after adding a campground. But unless I reload the page, fresh data isn't retrieved.

I figured it has something to do with React's lifecycle methods.

Code:

**manageCampground.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import '../../styles/addCampground.css'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';  
import {
  actionAddCampground,
  getCampgroundDetails,
  actionUpdateCampground
} from './actions/campgroundActions';

class AddCampground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      cost: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const campground = this.props.campground;
    if (campground._id) {
      this.props.getCampgroundDetails(campground._id);
      this.setState({
        name: campground.name,
        description: campground.description,
        cost: campground.cost
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  addCampground = () => {
    const name = this.state.name;
    const description = this.state.description;
    const cost = this.state.cost;
    this.props.actionAddCampground({
      name,
      description,
      cost
    });
    this.props.history.push('/home');
    console.log('Campground added successfully');
  };

  updateCampground = () => {
    const name = this.state.name;
    const description = this.state.description;
    const cost = this.state.cost;
    this.props.actionUpdateCampground({
      name,
      description,
      cost
    });
    this.props.history.push('/home');
    console.log('Updated successfully');
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <Card className="add-campground-card">
        <TextField
          name="name"
          className="textfield"
          label="Campground name"
          variant="outlined"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        <TextField
          name="description"
          className="textfield"
          label="Campground description"
          variant="outlined"
          value={this.state.description}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        <TextField
          name="cost"
          className="textfield"
          type="number"
          label="Campground cost"
          variant="outlined"
          value={this.state.cost}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        {!this.props.campground._id ? (
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={this.addCampground}>
            Add Campground
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className="update-campground-btn"
            onClick={this.updateCampground}>
            Update Campground
          </Button>
        )}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    campground: state.campgroundList.singleCampground || ''
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      actionAddCampground,
      getCampgroundDetails,
      actionUpdateCampground
    },
    dispatch
  );
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AddCampground);
```

**campgroundList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllCampgrounds } from './actions/campgroundActions';
import Header from '../common/Header';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import '../../styles/landingPage.css';

class CampgroundLanding extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllCampgrounds();
    console.log('From component did mount');
  }


  render() {
    const { campgrounds } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        {campgrounds.map(campground => (
          <Card className="campground-card" key={campground._id}>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" 
  component="h2">
                  {campground.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" 
  component="p">
                  {campground.description}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardActions>
              <Link
                style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}
                to={`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`}>
                <Button size="small" color="primary">
                  View Details
                </Button>
              </Link>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Learn More
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        ))}
        <Link
          style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}
          to="/campgrounds/add">
          <Button color="primary">Add Campground</Button>
        </Link>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    campgrounds: state.campgroundList.campgrounds
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      getAllCampgrounds
    },
    dispatch
  );
}; 


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(CampgroundLanding);
```

**campgroundActions.js**

```
import {
  GET_ALL_CAMPGROUNDS,
  ADD_CAMPGROUND,
  GET_CAMPGROUND_DETAILS,
  EDIT_CAMPGROUND
} from '../actionTypes/types';

import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = `http://localhost:5000/api`;

export const getAllCampgrounds = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .get(`${API_URL}/campgrounds`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_ALL_CAMPGROUNDS,
          payload: res
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
};

export const actionAddCampground = campground => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .post(`${API_URL}/campgrounds`, campground)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_CAMPGROUND,
          payload: res
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
};

export const getCampgroundDetails = id => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .get(`${API_URL}/campgrounds/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_CAMPGROUND_DETAILS,
          payload: res
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
};

export const actionUpdateCampground = id => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .put(`${API_URL}/campgrounds/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        dispatch({
          type: EDIT_CAMPGROUND,
          payload: res
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
};
```

**campgroundReducers.js**

```
import {
  GET_ALL_CAMPGROUNDS,
  ADD_CAMPGROUND,
  GET_CAMPGROUND_DETAILS,
  EDIT_CAMPGROUND
} from '../actionTypes/types';

const initialState = {
  campgrounds: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_CAMPGROUNDS:
      const { campgroundList } = action.payload.data;
      state.campgrounds = campgroundList;
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case ADD_CAMPGROUND:
      const { campground } = action.payload.data;
      return {
        ...state,
        campground
      };
    case GET_CAMPGROUND_DETAILS:
      const { singleCampground } = action.payload.data;
      return { ...state, singleCampground };
    case EDIT_CAMPGROUND:
      const { editedCampground } = action.payload.data;
      return { ...state, editedCampground };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If I'm using componentDidUpdate, it's leading to infinite loop.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.campgrounds !== this.props.campgrounds) {
    this.props.getAllCampgrounds();
  }
}
```

I know I'm going wrong somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Maybe you should try to add retrieve data step to your add logic so then when you add new campground you retrieve your data again (or at least dispatch action again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix your `componentDidUpdate` method to avoid this infinity loop. Your are trying to compare objects via `===` method which will always fail according to this example:

```js
const a = {key: 1}
const b = {key: 1}
console.log(a === b); // false
```

You could use for example `isEqual` method from `lodash` module to compare objects like you want https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual

```js
console.log(_.isEqual({key: 1}, {key: 1})) // true
console.log({key: 1} === {key: 1}) // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Actually why do you want refresh data in this case? When you add object with success into the store this will refresh your component so you don't have to request for fresh data.

Comment: So the issue is that the campground I'm adding is being stored into the DB, but the Redux store is only fetching it on reload. What's going wrong?

Comment: Inside your reducer `ADD_CAMPGROUND` you have to add `campground` also to your `campgrounds` list: `return { ...state, campgrounds: [...state.campgrounds, campground], campground };` This will refresh your `CampgroundLanding` component.

Comment: Yeah, it works after your implementation. I wasn't adding the campground object to the campgroundsList array in the reducer, due to which it wasn't updating till I reloaded. Thank you! I learnt something new today.